# How to control triggering of email for the same error in ssis using event handlers?

Tags: ssis

I am using ssis event handler to trigger an email whenever an error occured in the entire package(PACKAGE+ONEEROR). Here number of emails triggered is equal to number of errors generated.How can I restrict it to one mail eventhough the same error occured 10 times.

Please suggest....

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. The problem with setting an ONERROR email at the package level is that it will send an email for each error the package encounters. This gets ugly if you have a deep level transform fail, which will error as it fails back up to the package level.

I suggest that you either:
1) Setup ONERROR events at the task level and remove the package level event. Usually this will be good enough. Most tasks will only have one error to report. Be careful with Data Flows, they can act in a similar fashion as the package level events.

2) Setup some sort of advance logging. I’ve seen this done several ways. I’ve seen some people setup Script tasks to log the errors (at the task level) to a variable, and then send a final email containing the variable in the body (at control flow level). I have also seen people call stored procedures (at the task level and package level) for each error that occurs. The sproc would log errors to the DB and allow the package to continue on to the next step/container. The logged errors can then be dumped into a csv and emailed as an attachment.

If you like your current setup, you can try changing the error properties for each container/task. I haven't ever done this, but I do know you can change the way tasks handle errors! I don't like this option because you would possibly be missing errors (maybe? kind of guessing).

*update* From another solution - If you want to keep your current email ONERROR and simply prevent certain errors from "bubbling" up and sending emails, you can follow this [link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rushabh_mehta/archive/2008/04/24/gracefully-handing-task-error-in-ssis-package.aspx) to learn how to gracefully handle errors. You could prevent certain tasks errors from reaching your ONERROR event at the package level. good luck.